How to connect old Nokia 3220 phone to a modern computer? Or login to Drive on the phone? [to transfer data from phone]
I have an old Nokia 3220 mobile, which has an "Internet" app built-in. The phone does not have Bluetooth or Wi-Fi support.
Now, there are some files on the phone that I would like to keep (and I am worried the phone might stop working after two decades of use).
However, I am unable to login to my Google Drive account or Microsoft One Drive account, as I always get "not secure connection" messages whenever I try. The login pages load without any problem, but that's as far as I can go.
So the only solution seems to be to connect the phone to a modern computer. But I am at a total loss as to how to do that. The Wikipedia page for Nokia 3220 says that I would need a Nokia CA-42 Pop-Port cable. But I cannot find where to get that cable.
Amazon has some old Pop-port cables, but it doesn't say that it is compatible with Nokia 3220.
Can someone please help me out as to how to get that cable? Or, if somehow possible, how to login to a cloud/file storage service on my phone? Or, is there any other way of transferring those files to a modern phone/computer?
It would be immensely helpful if I can find a solution here.

There are a bunch of them on ebay,com

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - Thank you for the comment. I have searched on eBay, but I am not sure if they have the 14-pin Pop-Port connector. If possible, please share a link. :)

ebay.com - searched for: Nokia CA-42 Pop-Port cable Some of the results that seem like the right thing: https://www.ebay.com/itm/284263720831 https://www.ebay.com/itm/145688877299

Aren't you going to need access software that supports ancient phones and runs on modern systems?  The physical connection is just the start.

Could you transfer the data through NFC?  3220 was one of the first phones to have NFC

Apparently the web browser of your Nokia is too old to work with current real web servers. Did you consider to set up a virtual machine on your PC running a ready-made appliance, which provides a web server with upload capabilities? Then you have all the power to disable any security obstacle.

The certificates on the phone are probably out of date.  The usual work around is to tell the device to go through a HTTP proxy (which you must then provide)

If you can find the right cable, it may be possible to get a copy of the Nokia PC Suite software and install it in a Windows VM running Windows XP. Another option would be to use a proxy as @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen suggested, and as detailed in this question.

@thebusybee - Okay, now I am understanding a little. Can you please elaborate the "ready-made appliance" part (like, any examples of that)?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Thank you! So this HTTP proxy will allow secure connections to HTTPS websites/web-servers? Can you please elaborate a little?

@NoelWhitemore - Okay, I understand. It will be a pretty long process. Thanks a lot for sharing the link! :) I'll go through that.

Please see the link that noel whitemore gave.  You will need to do some learning to understand what is going on.

I don't know what your specific device supports to save files. You need to understand that and then use your favorite web search engine. For example, you can obtain different appliances from https://www.turnkeylinux.org/all.
